# Set user-agent for http requests for libraries which do not expose this setting?

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-socialauth

I am trying to do oauth authentication using Django-social-auth which uses oauth2 under the hood. I am adding a custom backend for vimeo. Vimneo API requires all APi calls to use a custom user-agent.

oauth2 is using httplib2 and doesn't have a hook point to set a user agent. Is there a way I can say "All network requests from here on should use this custom header".

Comment: Check my answer to your thread on the mailing list https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-social-auth/kCTSx_wU-Ag/I-JuUbPmnM4J

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, then you can send `User-Agent` alongwith request headers.

```
h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
resp, content = h.request("https://example.org/chap/2", 
    "PUT", body="This is text", 
    headers={'User-Agent':'my user agent'} )
```